# How to create a vector indicating matches between the elements of one vector and any element in another?

Tags: r, match

I am trying to create a vector indicating whether country names in a data frame match any value from a separate list.

The separate list of country names looks like this:

```
list = c("Canada", "China", "Brazil")
```

I have a large data frame containing a column vector with country names:

```
region = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
country = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "United States", "United States", "Brazil", "Brazil")       

df = data.frame(region, country)
df
```

I would like the end result to look something like:

```
matches <- c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1)

new_df = data.frame(df, matches)
new_df
```

The real data frame is very large. Is there a computationally efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
transform(df,match=as.numeric(country %in% list))
```

?

(I can't help pointing out that the `%in%` operator is covered on the [R help page for the "match" function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) ...)

Comment: Looking for dups sometimes hard because usually the titles are wrong.

Comment: I just tried searching for `[r] "%in%" match` but wasn't quickly coming with anything appropriate

Comment: My guess that looking for `%in%` won't be useful because OP usually doesn't know that this is what he looks for.

Comment: but it should be in the answers, right?  doesn't search index the answers too?