# Multiple conditions for ifelse statements in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

`responses$Status` has multiple statuses: `Invited, Attended, Registered, Downloaded, Sent, Added`

I tried to create a new binary column using this code:

```
responses$hasresponded <- ifelse(responses$Status == c("Responded", "Attended", "Downloaded", "Contacted", "Requested"),1,0)
```

This code runs, but it is not doing what I want it to do. That is, to code 1 for any of these  statuses `("Responded", "Attended", "Downloaded", "Contacted", "Requested")`, and 0 for the rest.

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`: `ifelse(responses$Status %in% c("Responded", "Attended", "Downloaded", "Contacted", "Requested"),1,0)`

Comment: probably a dupe but I don't know how to search for `%in%` effectively ...

Comment: @BenBolker [deja vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188063/how-to-create-a-vector-indicating-matches-between-the-elements-of-one-vector-and/29188098#29188098)

Answer (score 2):

`%in%` is your friend.

Splitting up a bit for readability:

```
OKresp <- c("Responded", "Attended", 
        "Downloaded", "Contacted", "Requested")
responses$hasresponded <- as.numeric(responses$Status %in% OKresp)
```

or

```
responses <- transform(responses,
          hasreponded = Status %in% OKresp)
```