# Dynamic conditions for subsetting in R

Tags: r

I have a list defined like so:

```
cond <- list(list(1), list(1, 2), list(1, 2, 3))
```

Based on this `cond` list I want to make subsetting. In a trivial hard-coded case, I do it like so:

```
t1 <- subset(dat, group == 1)
t2 <- subset(dat, group == 1 | group == 2)
# etc
```

Now I want to turn from this hard-coded solution to a dynamic one. In a pseudo-code it would look like so:

```
ts <- list()
i <- 1
for(lst in cond){
   ts[i] <- subset(dat, group in lst) # <- This is what I want
   i <- i + 1
}
```

In other words, I want to turn from this:

```
group == 1 | group == 2
```

to this:

```
group in lst
```

But I'm not sure how to really implement this.

Comment: You just need the `%in%` operator.

Comment: @joran. Thanks! I will check it in a minute.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188063/how-to-create-a-vector-indicating-matches-between-the-elements-of-one-vector-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need lists of lists, here. A list of vectors like

```
gs <- list(1, 1:2, 1:3)
```

should work fine, followed by

```
ts <- lapply(gs, function(x) dat[dat$group %in% x, ])
```

I don't use `subset` in light of this note from `?subset`:

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.

Comment: `subset()` would be fine in this case: `subset(dat, group %in% lst)`. The problem is really only when people try to specify columns via variables.

Comment: @MrFlick Best to cut off its usage before the OP gets that far :)